# Rails nested Attributes of join table won't be saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Nested attributes of join model won't be saved. relation id's seems to be missing. The following error messages are added when the fields get validated:

```
* Assigned projects user can't be blank
* Assigned projects project can't be blank
```

The submitted params look like this ( <%= debug(params) %> )

```
--- !map:ActionController::Parameters 
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
authenticity_token: HrF1NHrKNTdMMFwOvbYFjhJE1ltlKbuz2nsfBYYBswg=
project: !map:ActionController::Parameters 
  name: Peter Pan
  assigned_projects_attributes: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
    "0": !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      position: Group Leader
  currency: " Neverland Dollars"
commit: Add Project
action: create
controller: projects
```

I have 3 models, as followed:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assigned_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :assigned_projects
  has_many :created_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => :creator_id
end

class AssignedProject < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user,    class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :project, class_name: "Project"

    attr_accessible :project_id, :user_id, :position, :project_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project

    validates :user_id,     presence: true
    validates :project_id,  presence: true
    validates :position,    presence: true
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :assigned_projects
  has_many :users, :through => :assigned_projects
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :creator_id

  attr_accessible :name, :creator_id, :currency :assigned_projects_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assigned_projects

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 100 }
  validates :currency, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 5 }
  validates :creator_id, presence: true
end
```

So each User can create a Project. He can add any User to the Project through the join model.
Each Project belongs to a User resp. Creator and has_many user through assigned_projects

I want to give each user of a project a "position", which should be saved in the join model: assigned_project :position

the Project controller looks like that:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @project = Project.new
        @project.assigned_projects.build(user_id: current_user)
    end

    def create
        @project = current_user.assigned_projects.build.build_project(params[:project])
        @project.creator = current_user

        if @project.save
            redirect_to current_user
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

and the project/new.html.erb form looks like that:

```
<%= form_for( @project ) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :assigned_projects do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.label :position %>
        <%= ff.text_field :position%>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :currency %>
    <%= f.text_field :currency %>

    <%= f.submit "Add Project", class: "" %>                    
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE: current controller & view**

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    if @project.save
        redirect_to current_user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

<%= form_for( @project ) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :creator_id, value: current_user.id %>

    <%= f.fields_for :assigned_projects, @project.assigned_projects do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.label :position %>
        <%= ff.text_field :position%>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :currency %>
    <%= f.text_field :currency %>

    <%= f.submit "Add Project", class: "" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by removing the validations for project_id and user_id in the join table "AssignedProject"

So the join Model looks like that:

```
# Join Model AssignedProject
class AssignedProject < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user#,    class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :project#, class_name: "Project"

    attr_accessible :project_id, :user_id, :position, :project, :project_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project

    validates :position,  presence: { message: " can't be blank." }
end
```

The New and Create methods look like that:

```
# Projects Controller
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @project = Project.new
        @project.assigned_projects.build(user_id: current_user)
    end

    def create
        @project = Project.new(params[:project])

        if @project.save
            @project.assigned_projects.create(user_id: current_user)
            redirect_to current_user
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

And the form in the view for the new method looks like that:

```
<%= form_for( @project ) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :creator_id, value: current_user.id %>

    <%= f.fields_for :assigned_projects, @project.assigned_projects do |ff| %>

        <%= ff.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

        <%= ff.label :position %>
        <%= ff.text_field :position%>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :currency %>
    <%= f.text_field :currency %>

    <%= f.submit "Add Project", class: "" %>                    
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

### View:

I think you need to pass the objects collection `@project.assigned_projects` you built in the `new` action to the `fields_for`:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.fields_for :assigned_projects, @project.assigned_projects do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label :position %>
    <%= ff.text_field :position%>
<% end %>

<%= f.label :currency %>
<%= f.text_field :currency %>

<%= f.submit "Add Project", class: "" %>
```

### Controller:

If i understood the first line in the `create` action i think you try to re-build the project `assigned_projects` in-order to stamp the `creator` attribute !!

Instead you could **remove** this line and put a hidden field in the nested for, something like:

```
<%= ff.hidden_field :creator, current_user %>
```

So your controller looks pretty basic now:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:prject])
  if @project.save #nested objects will be saved automatically
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: good hint with the hidden field, although the tag should be in the f. section like `<%= f.hidden_field :creator_id, value: current_user.id %>` But the original problem is not solved. get the same error msg as described in the question!

Answer (score 0):

What does the build_project method do?
I think in your controller you should just have build, not build.build_project, so like this:

```
@project = current_user.assigned_projects.build(params[:project])
```

of if build_project is a method used to create the params then

```
 @project = current_user.assigned_projects.build(project_params)
```

in the case of rails 4 you would need something like this:

```
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:your_params)
end
```

In the case of rails 3 I think you need to add

```
attr_accessible :param1, :param2
```

in the project **model** for the parameters you want to set.

Comment: if I do it like you proposed I get the following error message: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, assigned_projects_attributes, currency` I have no clue where and what to add to the attr_accessible

Comment: it's not rails 4, it's rails ~> 3.2.13

Comment: I assume this is for rails 4?  Do a quick search on strong parameters in rails 4 for more info.

Comment: attr_accessible :name, :creator_id, :currency :assigned_projects_attributes  are you missing a comma on this line?

Comment: nope, comma is there. still getting the error **`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, creator_id, assigned_projects_attributes, currency`**

Comment: what happens if you try to assign them individually?  I assume that works?  Also maybe update/edit your question to show the latest version of the code you are working with (since things have changed)

Comment: the problem is **`@project.assigned_project.project_id = nil`**

Comment: Yes but how would you do that?

Comment: I guess \@project.assigned_project.project_id = nil because you never actually build an assigned_project. Assuming you have all the info for that coming in from your view you could just add it to the create action (above the \@project = ...), something like assigned_project.build(...).  to set field individually you would do something like \@project.currency = params[:project][:currency].  Hope that helps

Comment: i added the \ before the \@ because the comment function thinks i was trying to direct my comments to project :)